# jQuery see if key existing in entire JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've got some JSON data in which I'm trying to check if a key is contained in the entire array and add a class or do something else. If there is one key contained in the array I want to perform an action otherwise if there is no key do something. I've been banging my head for hours ,inArray doesn't seem to be working for me or hasOwnProperty. I've got to be doing something stupid simple wrong here. Kind of a newb so please include code samples were applicable.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtC4G/

```
var data={"users":[
    {
        "firstName":"Ray",
        "lastName":"Villalobos",
        "userName":"rvilla",
        "joined": {
            "month":"January",
            "day":12,
            "year":2012
        }
    },
    {
        "firstName":"John",
        "lastName":"Jones",
        "joined": {
            "month":"April",
            "day":28,
            "year":2010
        }
    },
    {
        "firstName":"John",
        "lastName":"Johnson",
        "userName": "jjoe"
    }
]}

if($.inArray('userName', data.users) == -1) { alert('not in array'); }

if(data.users.hasOwnProperty('userName')){
alert('do something');
}
```

Comment: So you want to do something for `rvilla` and `jjoe` because they have usernames? Or do you mean that because the array has at least one thing with a `userName`, you want to do something?

Comment: `var found = data.users.some(function(o) { return "firstName" in o })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[` indicates an array, so you need to treat it as an array (`data.users[0]`, not just `data.users`):

```
if($.inArray('userName', data.users[0]) == -1) { alert('not in array'); }

if(data.users[0].hasOwnProperty('userName')){
    alert('do something');
}
```

Comment: I think, `hasOwnPorperty` makes no sense in this context. If you have an object literal, all properties are its _own_,

Comment: Seems like this one's brought you into the `10k` club, congrats Ed ;-) added a +1 too, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

you can compare a variable with a undefined value

```
for(user_index in data.users){
    user=data['users'][user_index];
    if(user.userName==undefined){
        alert('username undefined in user '+user.firstName+' '+user.lastName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To find out, whether a property is set, I would go for a native JS.solution:

```
 function containsKey(key){ return function(el){
     return el[key]!==undefined;
 }};

 containsUserName=containsKey("userName");

 console.log(data.users.some(containsUserName))
```

This is all you need. 
`containsKey` is a closure, which saves the key, for which you are looking for.

`containsUsername` is the function, which is used to look for a specific property.

Read the *MDN* documentation of [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for compatibility etc.

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7EGp/) to play with.

If you want to extract that element: [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) might be of interest.